# converting lists to dataframe creates strings with 'b' before them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list in python3.6 which when i turn into a Dataframe inputs a 'b' in front of the all the strings.

for example:

```
x=[['a','b','c',1,2,3],['a1','b1','c1',1,2,3]]
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
```

where df will be:

```
b'a',b'b',b'c',1,2,3
 b'a1','b'b1','b'c1',1,2,3
```

any ideas how to create a literal translation from a list to a dataframe

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: Can't reproduce, Python 3.6.4 and pandas 0.20.3. I also think you meant `x` to be `[['a','b','c',1,2,3],['a1','b1','c1',1,2,3]] `

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah sorry about that, changed it now.

Comment: @matthewr You should add the exact code you are running which outputs the output you see